# Why do I get different results when variables are identified as Factor and Int in Generalized Linear Model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I have several independent variables. One of the independent variables (I'm calling Var1) has names of different sites (named A,B,C,D,E). This same variable has been coded as 1,2,3,4 and 5 (which I will call Var2, but is exactly the same as Var1 just in a different format). R (using `str(data)`) recognizes the independent variable  Var1 as "`Factor`" but identifies Var2 as "`int`". When I use these variables in two separate models (of course), I get two different results. Why is that? Also, do I need to specify that Var2 is a factor before running the GLM?

Comment: I am voting to leave this open because a) It already has a useful answer and b) The same issue could arise in other software packages. E.g. in SAS, if you have a variable that is coded with integers you will get different results if you put it on a CLASS statement.

Comment: pretty sure it's a duplicate (aside possibly from the GLM part which is of no impact). Can't check now; will try later

Comment: Thank you. I notice that SPSS gives me slightly different results from R using the same data @Peter Flom

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a duplicate too.  So far searches have only turned up the closely-related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120711 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260073.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R doesn't know that your variable is nominal (which I assume it should be, if it means sites). More precisely, it knows for `Var1` because using letters will make it to have a type of `character` which will be forced to be `factor` when put to a regression model. This is the correct approach, However, for `Var2` it will consider it as a usual a quantitative variable, measured on scale (just as you correctly observed that it has a type of `int`).

Both can be estimated, but it'll be meaningless in the second case: the coefficient will pertain to "site being 1 unit higher all else equal". `Var2` can indeed be one unit higher, but the site can't. In other words, `Var2` implies that the sites are ordered *and* their difference is the same (none of which is true, at least not because of the variable's nature - as R assumes).

Solution: you *can* use the format of `Var2`, but in that case, you have to tell R that it is a factor! E.g. `Var2 <- as.factor( Var2 )` run before the regression will solve your problem. However, you might wish to change the reference level (you can use `relevel` to do this, after the variable is declared to be a `factor`).

Comment: Thank you @Tamas Ferenci for this very clear explanation that makes a lot more sense to me. I do have two more questions: 1 - Can I still use Var1 as R recognizes Var1 as a factor or not? 2 - Could you please clarify for me your last sentence about changing the reference level, as in why I would need to do that and how do I decide which one it needs to be changed to? Many thanks - very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @EleMan 1) Yes, you can use `Var1`. Although it is not a factor, but a character, but character type automatically gets converted to factor when put into a regression model. 2) Let's say you have 10 patients from site 1, 100 from site 2 and 10 from site 3. Statistically it is the best to use that level as a reference, which has the highest frequency (the modal outcome), in this case, 2. Or, 2 is - for some subject area reason - the one, to which you want to compare everything else. Bottomline is, you want 2 to be the reference category. ...

Comment: ...however, simply using `as.factor(Var2)` won't give you this, because it'll take the lowest value as the reference level, 1 in this case. So you'll need `relevel(Var2,ref=2)` in this case to set the reference category correctly.

Comment: Great, thank you again for your explanation. I will try that.

Comment: Tamas Ferenci and @Peter so I just noticed that by using <Var1> (names of sites), R still automatically takes the site that begins with an 'A' as the reference category. I did try to use <relevel(Var1,ref=C)> as I want site C to be the reference category, but that did not work. It still took the site with the name beginning with A. Is there a way around this as opposed to using Var2 and specifying a ref=3 category? Thanks.

Comment: `relevel(Var1,ref=C)` should be `relevel(Var1,ref="C")` (note the quotation mark). Did you actually replace the variable (i.e. have you run `Var 1 <- relevel(Var1,ref="C")`) before putting it to the regression model? You'll actually need `Var1 <- relevel(as.factor(Var1),ref="C")` if you have not already converted Var1 to factor.

Comment: perfect!!!! That worked exactly the way I think it should have worked. Thank you so much. That really helped. One last question here: How do I know whether the model overall is significant or not, like SPSS gives a separate overall model significance? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. `anova(fit)` gives you the global test (but `summary(fit)` also displays it).

Comment: :( sorry, I just tried that, and googled it, found somewhere that I needed a 'fit' package and installed it, but I get error messages saying" > summary(fit)
Error in summary(fit) : object 'fit' not found
> annova(fit)
Error in annova(fit) : could not find function "annova"

Comment: `fit` is simply the name of the regression object, sorry, I forget to write it down. `fit<-glm(...)`.

Comment: Cheers!!! Thank you so much! You're brilliant! :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm just reopening this but looking at this answer: <http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/R/R7_LogisticRegression-Survival/R7_LogisticRegression-Survival3.html> it seems like the model overall significance is given by 1-pchisq(Null deviance -Residual deviance, Null deviance degrees of freedom - Residual deviance degrees of freedom). Does that seem right, as I don't get model significance overall using anova() or summary().

Comment: @EleMan Sorry. You're right, I mixed `glm` and `lm`. You can find the answer for `glm` [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129958/glm-in-r-which-pvalue-represents-the-goodness-of-fit-of-entire-model).

Comment: No worries, thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

`R` will treated `Var2` as numbers and do a regression on the values. Since they are not numbers but categories, you will need to tell it that `Var2` is a factor before fitting your model.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about R, but the same thing can happen with other packages. This is one reason to try not to code categorical variables with numeric codes - it eliminates one very easy way to carelessly mess up.  (I am always eager to prevent my own carelessness or that of other people).

Comment: I see...yeah, so you're suggesting that I just leave var1 as site "names" rather than code the sites and then treat those values as factors? Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: Yes. Less opportunity to do something silly.